# Windows serial port read line

Tags: windows, serial-port

I have been trying to write an simple C code to use the serial port with windows, I need to read lines (ended with \n + \r) and then save it to a file. My problem is that I didn't found a good way of doing it.

First, I need to be able to close the serial port at any time, so I've decided to write an multithread program. Well, the multithread works as expected, and I'm trying to use OVERLAPED communication because NON-OVERLAPED reads blocks for ever while not receiving data (remember, I need to close the port at any time).

Can anyone post an simple code to read 1 line from serial port in C/C++ ?

**Update 1**

I've tried to write an function like 'SerialReadLine(Handle SerialPort, char Buffer[]);' where I use an loop to issue multiple ReadFile (byte per byte) until I receive the line ending (\n + \r).

Now I'm trying to use NON-OVERLAPPED I/O with timeouts, it's almost working, but the timouts doesn't:

```
bool SerialReadLine (const HANDLE *_SerialPort , char String_out[])
{
    DWORD ReadBytes;
    char BufferSerial[2];
    unsigned int CharCount = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        if (ReadFile(*_SerialPort, &BufferSerial, 1, &ReadBytes, NULL))
        {
            if ((ReadBytes > 0) && (BufferSerial[0] != '\n') && (BufferSerial[0] != '\r'))
            {
                String_out[CharCount] = BufferSerial[0];
                CharCount++;
            }
            else if (BufferSerial[0] == '\r')
            {
                String_out[CharCount] = '\0';
                return  true;
            }
        }
        else //If ReadFile() returns 0, a timeout have ocurred
        {
            if (!(SerialIsOpen)) return false; //SerialIsOpen is a global
                                               //variable used to close the
                                               //serial port through main thread
        }
    }

}
```

And to config the timeouts:

```
COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts;

timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 10;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 10;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 10;


if (!SetCommTimeouts(SerialPort, &timeouts)) //Returns successful
{
    printlog (TEXT("Something is wrong!\n\r"));
}
```

Comment: The Microsoft documentation on using serial i/o seems pretty good, including code samples that do what you're asking for.  Can you explain more specifically what part you're having problems with?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff802693.aspx

Comment: You might not need to use overlapped I/O if that's your only problem; are you aware of the `CancelSynchronousIo` function?

Comment: Are you really sure that you really have (and want to have) lines ending with "\n\r"? Because the common line ending on windows is "\r\n".

Comment: I'm sorry for taking so long to reply. CancelSynchronousIo doesn't work when called from another thread.

I'll try to reorganize my code to make it more readable.